# Multi tenancy springboot

Tags: aplicação-web, spring-boot, multi-tenancy

Como fazer para o spring manter o tenantID presente em todas as requisições? Gostaria de salientar que a minha ideia para a utilização do multitenant seria da seguinte maneira `www.nomeDoSistema.com.br/nomeDaEmpresa/`
e para cada nome da empresa o sistema ira fixar um único banco para este cliente.
Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Esse é meu problema de lida diária. Infelizmente acabei de desligar o computador para dar as diretrizes. De modo geral, tenho um `TenantRoutingDatasource` do HikaiCP que gerencia a rota do tenant para o `Datasource`. Mantenho o `tenant` numa `ThreadLocal` devidamente encapsulada e tenho um `Filter` que vai setar o tenant adequado.

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse artigo e veja se te ajuda no seu problema: https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7